# How does Linux determine what facilities to use to run a (non-text) binary?

Tags: linux, executable

I understand that Linux uses shebang line to determine what interpreter to use for scripting languages, but how does it work for binaries?

I mean I can run Linux binaries, and having installed both *wine* and *mono*, Windows native and .NET binaries. And for all of them it's just `./binary-name` (if not in PATH) to run it.

How does Linux determine that a given binary must be run as a Linux native binary, as a Windows native binary (using *wine* facilities) or as a Windows .NET binary (using *mono* facilities)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In a word: [binfmt_misc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc). It's a Linux-specific, non-portable, facility.

There are a couple of formats that are recognized by the kernel with built-in logic. Namely, these are the ELF format (for normal binaries) and the shebang convention (for scripts). (thanks to [zwol](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21167/zwol) for the following part of the answer). In addition, Linux recognizes a couple of esoteric or obsolete or compatibility builtin formats. You probably won't encounter them. They are `a.out`, "em86", "flat", and "elf_fdpic".

Everything else must be registered through the binfmt_misc system. This system allows you to register with the kernel a simple pattern check based on a magic number, and the corresponding interpreter.

Comment: Although the OP asked for Linux explicitly, it could be worth noting that unlike many other solutions that work both on Linux and other Unix-like systems, this one is totally Linux-specific.

Comment: It might not be compiled in, but the Linux source tree still includes intrinsic support for `a.out`, "em86", "flat", and "elf_fdpic" formats as well as normal ELF.  All of those except em86 appear to be native binary executable formats; there isn't enough information for me to figure out when one would use "flat" or "elf_fdpic".  em86 appears to be a pre-binfmt\_misc mechanism for running a particular x86 emulator, it's probably only still around for backward compatibility.

Comment: On Debian Linux (I didn't check RedHat and others) the command to display all current binfmt entries is `update-binfmts --display`